# Wp Admin Bar Customizing Labels

Tags: title, admin-bar, customization

I would like to replace the Label the Plugin WP Custome Area sets on the admin bar.
This is the initial parto of code that sets the menu title:

```
public function build_adminbar_menu($wp_admin_bar)
{
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
        'id'    => 'customer-area',
        'title' => __('WP Custome Area', 'cuar'),
        'href'  => admin_url('admin.php?page=wpca')
    ));
```

This is the hook i tried but without any joy...

```
function replace_content()
{
$content = $wp_admin_bar->get_node('customer-area');
$content->title = __('Custom Title', 'cuar');
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use add_filter with the_content that way; that is meant for a different context - when you are filtering a returned WP post object.

Try something like this instead:

```
function replace_customer_area_title( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $newtitle = __('Custom Title', 'cuar');
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array( 'id' => 'customer-area', 'title' => $newtitle, ) );
}

add_filter( 'admin_bar_menu', 'replace_customer_area_title' , 33 );
```

`add_node` should modify an existing node, if found.

This must run after the original node was added with priority of 32, so we have used 33 here as an example.

Comment: Thanks CC and birgire for your great solution!! It works perfectly with the editing :)